# Algorithm to spread / declutter points in 1 dimension (on a line)

Tags: algorithm, line, mathematical-optimization, point

Is there a non-iterative algorithm to spread out / declutter points on a line?

**Example:**

Upper line: Initial situation. Lower line: Points have been spread out.

[image]

**Constraints:**

- I would prefer to have a solution that is not based on nudging the points until they stabilize. In other words, I would prefer an algorithm which, for example, solves a set of equations and thus compute the new position for all points "in one go".
- It's a 1-dimensional situation.
- The resulting points should be as close to their initial positions as possible, but maintain some minimal fixed distance to it's neighbors. Approximations are fine though.

Comment: Since this is along one dimension it should be much easier. You could try to build a function f : R+ -> R+ that maps the distance between two adjacent points before spreading to the distance between those points after spreading, such that it increases small distances and decreases large distances, and such that the total sum f(d(p0, p1)) + f(d(p1, p2)) + ... + f(d(p(n-1), pn)) is equal to the original total sum d(p0,p1) + d(p1,p2) + ... + d(p(n-1),pn)

Comment: That could be one way to think about it. Unclear to me how to translate that to an algorithm however.

Comment: Other possibility: classify every distance between adjacent points as either "Large" or "small". On your example image, we get L,s,L,L,s,s,s,L. Note how every large distance separates two clusters of points. Then replace every small distance by the "minimal fixed distance" you want. Then decrease every large distance by half the total distance that was added to the cluster on its left and half the total distance that was added to the cluster on its right.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but this looks like a simple LP which might might be interpreted as iterative as well as algebraic / combinatorial (at least Simplex, not IPM). Not sure what *in one go* means or why it's even a requirement.

Comment: @Stef, the problem with that approach is that, once I have replace all the `s` distances with a minimal distance, the new locations may have approach other distant points. Perhaps even gone past them!

Comment: @sascha, could very well be a simple LP. Do you happen to know roughly how such algorithm would be expressed?

Comment: Given are points `p_i` (sorted non-descending). Introduce *n vars* `x_i` with same cardinality. Minimize `sum of |x_i - p_i| over all i` subject to: `x1 - x0 >= min`, `x2 - x1 >= min, ...`. (the absolute-value would need *linearization* as described in many textbooks) The constraints somewhat represent a *simple temporal network* which might be another thing to look at (*all-pairs shortest-paths* can infer the tightest bounds in O(n^3), but there is still some need of *shifting*, deciding on the start(s). The LP should does all that for free.

Comment: Thank you @sascha, this is probably what I'm looking for. I will do some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small general-purpose mathematical-optimization based demo:

- LP/QP might differ as *penalties* are weighted differently!
- *cvxpy* does give us the necessary linearizations / reformulations for free (e.g. `abs`)

```python
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([3, 4, 10, 13, 14, 15]) 
min_distance = 2

def solve(quadratic):
  # vars
  x = cp.Variable(points.shape[0])

  # constraints
  constrs = [x[i] - x[i-1] >= min_distance for i in range(1, points.shape[0])]

  # objective
  if not quadratic:
    obj = cp.Minimize(sum(cp.abs(x - points)))
  else:
    obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x - points))

  # setup problem + solve
  problem = cp.Problem(obj, constrs)
  problem.solve()

  return x.value

linear_sol = solve(False)
quad_sol = solve(True)

# visualize
f, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)

colors = [plt.cm.tab10(i) for i in range(points.shape[0])]

ax0.set_title('Input data')
ax1.set_title('linear / abs | LP')
ax2.set_title('quadratic / sum-squares | QP')

for ind, _ in enumerate(points):
  ax0.axvline(points[ind], color=colors[ind])
  ax1.axvline(linear_sol[ind], color=colors[ind])
  ax2.axvline(quad_sol[ind], color=colors[ind])

f.suptitle("Min distance = {}".format(min_distance))
plt.show()
```

which behaves like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Will read up carefully on this solution. Also need to try to translate it to JavaScript :-P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible algorithm.

- Classify every distance between adjacent points as either `Large` or `small`. On your example image, we get `L,s,L,L,s,s,s,L`.
- Note how every `Large` distance separates two clusters of points.
- Replace every small distance by the "minimal fixed distance" you want.
- Decrease every large distance by half the total distance that was added to the cluster on its left and half the total distance that was added to the cluster on its right.

The algorithm takes two parameters: the `minimal_distance` wanted between adjacent points, and a `threshold` to differentiate between large distances and small distances.

### Implementation in python

```py
import itertools  # groupby, accumulate

points = [0, 5, 6, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 24]

def get_distances(points):
  return [(b-a) for a,b in zip(points, points[1:])]

def group_by_large_or_small(distances, threshold):
  return itertools.groupby(distances, key=lambda d: (d > threshold))

def spread_cluster(cluster, minimal_distance):
  added_distance = 0
  new_cluster = []
  for d in cluster:
    new_cluster.append(max(d, minimal_distance))
    added_distance += (d - new_cluster[-1])
  return new_cluster, added_distance

def increase_small_distances(grouped_distances, minimal_distance):
  new_groups = []
  for k,g in grouped_distances:
    if k:
      new_groups.append((k, list(g), 0))
    else:
      new_cluster, added_distance = spread_cluster(g, minimal_distance)
      new_groups.append((k, new_cluster, added_distance))
  return new_groups

def decrease_large_distances(grouped_distances):
  distances = []
  for i, (k, g, a) in enumerate(grouped_distances):
    if k:
      g[0] += grouped_distances[i-1][2] / 2 if (i > 0 and not grouped_distances[i-1][0]) else 0
      g[-1] += grouped_distances[i+1][2] / 2 if (i+1 < len(grouped_distances) and not grouped_distances[i+1][0]) else 0
    distances.extend(g)
  return distances

def get_points(distances):
  return list(itertools.accumulate(distances, initial=0))

def spread_points(points, threshold, minimal_distance):
  distances = get_distances(points)
  grouped_distances = group_by_large_or_small(distances, threshold)
  grouped_distances = increase_small_distances(grouped_distances, minimal_distance)
  distances = decrease_large_distances(grouped_distances)
  return get_points(distances)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [0, 5, 6, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 24]
new_points = spread_points(points, 3, 1.6)

plt.scatter(points, [2 for _ in points])
plt.scatter(new_points, [1 for _ in points])
plt.show()
```

### Output

[image: Example of Spread Points]